# LINQ Double GroupBy and Format Result Into Array

Tags: c#, linq

Having the below:

```
Methods = dbExpenses
                    .SelectMany(e => e.UserExpenses, (expense, ue) => new { expense, ue })
                    .GroupBy(e => new { e.ue.Method, e.ue.UserId })
                    .Select(x => new GetInsightsByMethodDto {
                        Method = x.First().ue.Method.ToString(),
                        Frequency = x.Count()
                    }).ToList()
```

I have successfully grouped the result by both `Method` and `UserId` and the response is correct as such:

```
"methods": [
  {
    "method": "Cash",
    "frequency": 1
  },
  {
    "method": "Cash",
    "frequency": 2
  },
  {
    "method": "Transfer",
    "frequency": 1
  }
]
```

User one has used both *Card* and *Transfer* with the frequency of 1 for each. However user two has used *Cash* with a frequency of 2. So as you can tell, the first object in the array is for user one as well as the last item. However, the second item is for user two.

The desired output however is the below:

```
  "methods": [{
      "method": "Cash",
      "frequency": 1
    },
    {
      "method": "Transfer",
      "frequency": 1
    }
  ], [{
    "method": "Cash",
    "frequency": 2
  }]
```

Which consists of a *second* `array` for the other user.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Hi, maybe you should group by UserId before in order to obtain 2 objects in list. 
The first for User one, and the second for User two. 
Inside each array you should get their method and frequency.

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni Hello thanks for helping out but isn't the code you have here exactly identical to the one i pasted above?

Comment: sorry, I'm editing it

Comment: Methods = dbExpenses
                    .SelectMany(e => e.UserExpenses, (expense, ue) => new { expense, ue })
                    .GroupBy(e => new { e.ue.Method, e.ue.UserId })
                    .Select(x => new NewModelDto {
                        UserId = x..First().ue.UserID,
                        Methods&Frequency = new GetInsightsByMethodDto {
                                               Method = x.First().ue.Method.ToString(),
                                               Frequency = x.Count()
                    }).ToList();
Then, you'll group by userId